# Error installing rails on fedora 23

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

got a fresh installation of Fedora 23. Installed ruby using:

```
sudo yum install ruby
```

Everything ok so far. Then I tried:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

After that, I got the error:

```
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160225-4730-qcjlvb.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Anyone knows what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo yum install ruby-devel`

You need to install a Ruby development environment to install native extensions, which are written in C.

You may also need gcc, which you can install with `sudo yum install gcc`